# How do I disable amp-img default lightbox functionality?

Tags: amp-html, amp-img

I have a lot of `<amp-img>` elements on a client's site and recently noticed a feature where you can click the image and get a lightbox that pops out with an X in the upper-right corner. I can't find ANY mention on their [official documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-img/) about enabling/disabling this feature. I am using this element for some background/stylistic elements, so I'd rather users not be able to click it. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the code I'm using, with classes and URLs removed:

```
<amp-img
    width="2000"
    height="515"
    layout="responsive"
    src="https://image.url">
    <amp-img placeholder
        src="https://placeholder.url"
        layout="fill">
    </amp-img>
</amp-img>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do so by adding `data-amp-auto-lightbox-disable` attribute on any element. For more info see [this comment on Github](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/24531#issuecomment-531917639).